# Обработать завершение программы через taskkill и вывести в консоль

Tags: c#, .net-core

Например запускаем программу, и она ожидает что-то на ввод, и в это время через консоль мы прописываем `taskkill /PID id /f`. Какой обработчик нужно описать в коде, чтобы при таком он выводил  "Меня принудительно остановили".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1119869/2881286